# tuple' object has no attribute 'is_valid'

Tags: python, django

I'm just new at coding and I tried to create a user registration and watch the tutorials on youtube, I followed all the steps but suddenly got an error in views.py and this is the message error I got

````
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
from fyeah import f


def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST),
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('I-grade-home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})```


this is where my error appears
``` if form.is_valid():```
````

Comment: Why do you have a comma after `UserCreationForm(request.POST)`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is located here:

```py
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST),
        if form.is_valid():
```

The fact that you add a comma after `UserCreationForm(request.POST)` creates a tuple `(UserCreationForm(...), None)`. When you call `is_valid()`, it applies to the tuple and not the form, which is the first element.

Just take the comma off, and your problem will be solved.

```py
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
```